# iOS iPhone how to convert a UIImage into a PDF while preserving scale?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uiimage, pdf-generation

I got a 640x960 `UIImage` of the screen, which is nice and crisp when re-displayed on the retina display. I'm thinking of a way to convert this image into a nice crisp PDF document page.

How would I go about converting a UIImage into a PDF page?

Do I need to make the resulting PDF to be 640x960, or does PDF automatically scale content (ex: 320x480 with the scale factor of 2)?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to scale it by yourself. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6566696/641062) link would help you in converting view to PDF.

Answer (score 0):

UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(CGSize size); - not retina 
UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSize size, BOOL opaque, CGFloat scale) - retina

Comment: plz help me jpg to pdf convertor