# how to save a pie graph in pdf file in iphone app

Tags: iphone

I have iphone app which created Pie Chart i want that chart should be save in pdf file in iphone.

Below is the code for PieChart but how can i save it in pdf i have read that we can save text in pdf but how to save this

```
   -(void)createGraph{

  PieClass *myPieClass=[[PieClass alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(400,40, 320, 230)];


  myPieClass.itemArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:textFieldOne.text,textFieldTwo.text,textFieldThree.text, nil];

 myPieClass.myColorArray=[[NSArray alloc]initWithObjects:[UIColor purpleColor],[UIColor redColor],[UIColor orangeColor], nil];

 myPieClass.radius=100;
 [self.view addSubview:myPieClass];

  [self creatPDFFromView:@"mydata.pdf"];

 }

    -(void)createPDFfromUIView:(UIView*)aView saveToDocumentsWithFileName:(NSString*)aFilename


     {
```

// Creates a mutable data object for updating with binary data, like a byte array

```
  NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];
```

// Points the pdf converter to the mutable data object and to the UIView to be converted

```
 UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, aView.bounds, nil);
 UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
 CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();
```

// draws rect to the view and thus this is captured by UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData

```
   [aView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];
```

// remove PDF rendering context

```
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
```

// Retrieves the document directories from the iOS device

```
   NSArray* documentDirectories =   NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);

  NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
  NSString* documentDirectoryFilename = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:aFilename];
```

// instructs the mutable data object to write its context to a file on disk

```
 [pdfData writeToFile:documentDirectoryFilename atomically:YES];
 NSLog(@"documentDirectoryFileName: %@",documentDirectoryFilename);
 }
```

Comment: Maybe this could help:

[How to Convert UIView to PDF within iOS?][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443166/how-to-convert-uiview-to-pdf-within-ios

Answer (score 1):

Which view you want to create as a pdf in that view do the following changes

```
NSString *fileName=@"PdfFromView.pdf";
[self createPDFfromUIView:self.view saveToDocumentsWithFileName:fileName];


-(void)createPDFfromUIView:(UIView*)aView saveToDocumentsWithFileName:(NSString*)aFilename
{
// Creates a mutable data object for updating with binary data, like a byte array
NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];

// Points the pdf converter to the mutable data object and to the UIView to be converted
UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, aView.bounds, nil);
UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


// draws rect to the view and thus this is captured by UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData

[aView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];

// remove PDF rendering context
UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

// Retrieves the document directories from the iOS device
NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);

NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
NSString* documentDirectoryFilename = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:aFilename];

// instructs the mutable data object to write its context to a file on disk
[pdfData writeToFile:documentDirectoryFilename atomically:YES];
NSLog(@"documentDirectoryFileName: %@",documentDirectoryFilename);
```

}

After this code has been executed go to documents folder you will find the pdf document containing the same contents of that view you have passed in

> Blockquote

[self createPDFfromUIView:**self.view** saveToDocumentsWithFileName:fileName]

> Blockquote

this method call.
this code working fine Thanks to Antonio

Comment: this code is working fine but i don't see my data in pdf file

Comment: the code is working but i did not see any data in my pdf file

Comment: UITextView *textView=[[UITextView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0,320,250)];
 textView.text=@"This is the Textview Content";
 [self.view addSubview:textView];

NSString *fileName=@"PdfFromView.pdf";
[self createPDFfromUIView:self.view saveToDocumentsWithFileName:fileName];

**now you find that textview content is in a pdf document**

Answer (score 0):

Took from here:

[How to Convert UIView to PDF within iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443166/how-to-convert-uiview-to-pdf-within-ios)

```
(void)createPDFfromUIView:(UIView*)aView saveToDocumentsWithFileName:(NSString*)aFilename
{
    // Creates a mutable data object for updating with binary data, like a byte array
    NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];

    // Points the pdf converter to the mutable data object and to the UIView to be converted
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, aView.bounds, nil);
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
    CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


    // draws rect to the view and thus this is captured by UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData

    [aView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];

    // remove PDF rendering context
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    // Retrieves the document directories from the iOS device
    NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);

    NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* documentDirectoryFilename = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:aFilename];

    // instructs the mutable data object to write its context to a file on disk
    [pdfData writeToFile:documentDirectoryFilename atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"documentDirectoryFileName: %@",documentDirectoryFilename);
}
```

Comment: and how to give file name to this file afilename

Comment: and may i call this method [self creatPDFFromView:fileName];

Comment: It's just an example, copy the code and do what you want with it, but if you want to use it as a method, yes, call it like for ex:  [self creatPDFFromView:@"myFile.pdf"];

Comment: can we chat on this to talk for this solution please if you are free

Comment: I have tried this but getting exception as your given code with my implementation