# Gnerate pdf from html using phonegap and IOS plugin

Tags: ios, pdf, plugins, cordova

Here is the link to generate pdf in ios but I want to make a plugin with same code for phonegap so that I can use it for my app which is build with html, css and js.
Someone please advise, how can I call the same function with js to generate pdf on background.
[How to Convert UIView to PDF within iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443166/how-to-convert-uiview-to-pdf-within-ios/6566696#6566696)

Comment: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/UQGszrA0gVU

Comment: How about the javascript only alternative jsPDF? http://parall.ax/products/jspdf

Comment: Finally I have written native code and made a plugin to generate pdf for phonegap.