# How to take a screen shot of a scroll view and attach to an email?

Tags: objective-c, screenshot

I have a UIScrollView that has content that needs to be emailed. The screenshot only captures the visible areas on the screen. The scroll view size is 768 x 2000. The method I am using at the moment is the following;

```
- (IBAction) Email
{
    UIImage* image = nil;

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(_scrollView.contentSize);
    {
        CGPoint savedContentOffset = _scrollView.contentOffset;
        CGRect savedFrame = _scrollView.frame;

        _scrollView.contentOffset = CGPointZero;
        _scrollView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, _scrollView.contentSize.width, _scrollView.contentSize.height);

        [_scrollView.layer renderInContext: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];
        image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

        _scrollView.contentOffset = savedContentOffset;
        _scrollView.frame = savedFrame;
    }
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

    NSData * imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.95);


    if ([MFMailComposeViewController canSendMail]) {

        MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
        mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;

        [mc addAttachmentData:imageData mimeType:@"image/jpeg" fileName:@"Attachment.jpeg"];
        [self presentModalViewController:mc animated:YES];

    }
}
```

Thanks for the replies. I realised I only had the scrollview as an outlet and not a property. Changed the code to the following and fixed the issue;

Comment: So, what is the problem? What part of your function is not working?

Comment: The above code only takes a screen shot of the visible view and not the whole scroll view. I assume the image context is incorrect to capture the whole scroll view

Comment: What about making a PDF of the view and emailing it? Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443166/how-to-convert-uiview-to-pdf-within-ios) for a how to.

Comment: Thanks for the replies. I realised I only had the scrollview as an outlet and not as a property as well. The resolution is quite poor though. Any ideas on how to improve image quality?

Comment: Try using `UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(_scrollView.contentSize,YES,0.0);` instead of `UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(_scrollView.contentSize);` to make sure that you generate the result in "retina" resolution.