# IOS Upload pdf file from document directory to server using post and PHP

Tags: php, ios, objective-c, pdf

I am working upload the pdf from the document directory. I have refer [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5443166/how-to-convert-uiview-to-pdf-within-ios) to convert the UIview to PDF and [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/936855/file-upload-to-http-server-in-iphone-programming) to upload the pdf to the server but the result is the pdf file zero byte.

Here is my code.
Xcode side:

```
-(NSMutableData *)createPDFDatafromUIView:(UIView*)aView
{
    NSMutableData *pdfData = [NSMutableData data];

    // Points the pdf converter to the mutable data object and to the UIView to be converted
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, aView.bounds, nil);
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
    CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();


    // draws rect to the view and thus this is captured by UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData

    [aView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];

    // remove PDF rendering context
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();

    return pdfData;
}

-(NSString*)createPDFfromUIView:(UIView*)aView saveToDocumentsWithFileName:(NSString*)aFilename
{
    NSMutableData *pdfData = [self createPDFDatafromUIView:aView];

    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, aView.bounds, nil);
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage();
    CGContextRef pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext();

    // draws rect to the view and thus this is captured by UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData
    [aView.layer renderInContext:pdfContext];
    // remove PDF rendering context
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext();
    // Retrieves the document directories from the iOS device
    NSArray* documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask,YES);

    NSString* documentDirectory = [documentDirectories objectAtIndex:0];
    NSString* documentDirectoryFilename = [documentDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:aFilename];

    // instructs the mutable data object to write its context to a file on disk
    [pdfData writeToFile:documentDirectoryFilename atomically:YES];
    NSLog(@"documentDirectoryFileName: %@",documentDirectoryFilename);
    NSLog(@"The pdf is saved in %@", documentDirectoryFilename);
    return documentDirectoryFilename;
}

-(IBAction)snapchot:(id)sender
{
    NSDate*todayDate = [NSDate date];
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
    [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"ddMMyyyy"];
    NSString *mytext = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.pdf",[dateFormatter stringFromDate:todayDate]];


    [self createPDFfromUIView:_myView saveToDocumentsWithFileName:mytext];
    NSData *datadat = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:mytext];
    NSString *urlString = @"http://localhost/pfy/uploadtestformpdf.php";
    NSString *filename = @"filename2";
    NSMutableURLRequest *request= [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] init];
    [request setURL:[NSURL URLWithString:urlString]];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    NSString *boundary = @"---------------------------14737809831466499882746641449";
    NSString *contentType = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"multipart/form-data; boundary=%@",boundary];
    [request addValue:contentType forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
    NSMutableData *postbody = [NSMutableData data];
    [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"userfile\"; filename=\"%@.pdf\"\r\n", filename] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithString:@"Content-Type: application/pdf\r\n\r\n"] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [postbody appendData:[NSData dataWithData:datadat]];
    [postbody appendData:[[NSString stringWithFormat:@"\r\n--%@--\r\n",boundary] dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [request setHTTPBody:postbody];

    NSData *returnData = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:nil error:nil];
    NSString *returnString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:returnData encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSLog(@"%@", returnString);
}
```

PHP side:

```
<?php 
$uploaddir = './uploaded/';
$file = basename($_FILES['userfile']['name']); $uploadfile = $uploaddir . $file; 
if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['userfile']['tmp_name'], $uploadfile)) { echo "Received file: $file";}
?>
```

Could you help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

General issues with your code notwithstanding, it looks like the issue is that you're uploading a blank file. Your method `createPDFfromUIView: saveToDocumentsWithFileName:` saves your file to the documents directory and returns the path to the file. However, you're not actually using the path that's being returned by the method when you populate your `NSData` object with the contents of the file. Change your code to capture the returned path string:

```
NSString *path = [self createPDFfromUIView:_myView saveToDocumentsWithFileName:mytext];
NSData *datadat = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:path];
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. After updated the code, it is worked successfully. Thanks.