# Create a PDF file from a UIScrollView in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, pdf, uiscrollview, scrollview

I want to create a PDF file from the contents of a UIScrollView.

```
func createPdfFromView(aView: UIView, saveToDocumentsWithFileName fileName: String) {
    let pdfData = NSMutableData()
    let height = 1754.0
    let width = 1240.0
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, CGRect(x:-30, y:15,width:width,height:height) , nil)
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPage()
    guard let pdfContext = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext() else { return }

    aView.layer.render(in: pdfContext)
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()

    if let documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first {
        let documentsFileName = documentDirectories + "/" + fileName
        debugPrint(documentsFileName)
        pdfData.write(toFile: documentsFileName, atomically: true)
    }
}
```

I would expect that the code generates a PDF oriented on the size of the content in the scrollview.

The code currently only generates a static PDF. If the content in the scrollview is bigger than the PDF page, the content is cut off.

Comment: Content in a `UIScrollView` (really, *any* scroll view), is only rendered when the OS deems it necessary (imagine a table view with 1,000 rows). So simply telling a layer to render isn't going to do what you're hoping.There are many, many examples already out there - I'd suggest searching for `swift pdf from uiscrollview` and see if don't find something that will fit your needs (or point you in the right direction).

Comment: Which view do you pass? Can you show us the call site? Do you pass the scroll view or the scrollview's contentView?

Comment: @HAS Yes it is an Spreadsheet generated by this [Spreadsheet](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/SpreadsheetView) framework.
The function call: `createPdfFromView(aView: spreadsheetView, saveToDocumentsWithFileName: "Spread.pdf")`

Comment: I also want to get PDF from complete spreadsheet view. Please help me if you got a solution for this

Comment: @ArpitJain Unfortunately, I did not get a usable solution for it.

Comment: @JonasDeichelmann did you find any solution ?

Comment: @Yodagama unfortunately no. I ended up with no PDF function in my App.

Comment: @JonasDeichelmann I could achieve this using this Cocoapods framework. In my case I wanted to make a PDF from Spreadsheet , so that this framework help me to add table with different column size and many more features which I had wanted  https://cocoapods.org/pods/SimplePDF

Comment: @Yodagama Nice! Do you mind creating an answer to my question, so others can easier find your solution?

Comment: Any ideas on how I could do this inside swiftUI?

Answer (score 0):

```
func createPdfFromView()
{
    // Set frame as per content of view

    self.spreadsheetView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.spreadsheetView.contentSize.width, height: self.spreadsheetView.contentSize.height)
    let pdfPageBounds: CGRect = self.spreadsheetView.frame
    let pdfData: NSMutableData = NSMutableData()

    // Rendering spreadsheetView
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFContextToData(pdfData, pdfPageBounds, nil)
    UIGraphicsBeginPDFPageWithInfo(pdfPageBounds, nil)
    self.spreadsheetView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
    UIGraphicsEndPDFContext()
    let documentDirectories = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true).first
    let documentsFileName = documentDirectories! + "/" + "pdfName.pdf"
    pdfData.write(toFile: documentsFileName, atomically: true)
    print(documentsFileName)

    // Reset spreadsheetView
    self.spreadsheetView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 64, width: self.view.frame.width, height: self.view.frame.height)
    self.spreadsheetView.layoutSubviews()
    self.spreadsheetView.layoutIfNeeded()
    self.spreadsheetView.reloadData()}
```

Hope it will help you to create PDF from the spreadsheet.

Ref. Github code Link: [SpreadsheetView](https://github.com/kishikawakatsumi/SpreadsheetView)

Comment: I didn't get the whole content view as pdf , only the visible rect

Answer (score 0):

I could achieve this using this Cocoapods framework. In my case I wanted to make a PDF from Spreadsheet , so that this framework help me to add table with different column size and many more features which I had wanted from my data.

https://cocoapods.org/pods/SimplePDF

Comment: Can You share the code or say how did you achieve that like what properties of `SimplePDF` you used ..i am also stuck at this rn